# How do I convert an Error object in node js to a string properly?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

This error throws up whenever I enter a duplicate entry in mysql.

`{ [Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'sample@gmail.com' for key 'email
'] code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY', errno: 1062, sqlState: '23000', index: 0 }`

What I want to do is turn this Error object into a string. I tried using JSON.stringify() and when I printed it on the console, only the last part got converted into a string :

`{"code":"ER_DUP_ENTRY","errno":1062,"sqlState":"23000","index":0}`

I need to convert the first part as well of the error, the one inside the [ ] so that I am able to diagnose duplicates properly. How do I retrieve that part whenever I convert an Error object into a string?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I thought I had to use JSON for this problem because of the way the Error object was formatted. How I solved this one was just to use

```
err.toString()
```

Comment: If you want full stack trace user err.stack 
 

https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_message

Answer (score 14):

To get the full stack use [`stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) property from the `Error` object:

```js
console.log(error.stack)
```

Answer (score 6):

For future reference, just in case you wish to extract the Error messsage. Use `error.message` to extract the message. Here is a reference: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_message

Answer (score 2):

Note that using `error.stack` does not include stacks of the nested errors. To get those, you can use `util.inspect()`

```js
const error = new Error('Too bad', { cause: new Error('Indeed') })
console.log(util.inspect(error))
```